# xml for numeric keypad with "-" and "/"

Tags: android, xml, ime

I have an edit field that accepts numbers, but I want to be able to show fractions like "3-1/2". The numeric soft keypad does not have the "-" and "/" symbols available.

Is there any way in xml code for the edit control to pop up the regular text soft keyboard with the alt "123" button (lower left) selected so that the numbers will show on the top row and the other symbols I need are available to the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard part of the sdk to write your own description of a keyboard, in XML format.  I haven't played around with it myself but it looks promising.